# Unable to upload images to Ubuntu (Digital Ocean)

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions

I have Laravel(PHP) site which is running well on a localhost as well as Hostgator Linux shared server. The website allows users to make accounts and upload images and documents in following two directories:

```
var/www/html/public/contents/individual/project/images
var/www/html/public/contents/individual/project/docs
```

**Now I have moved it to Ubuntu server at DigitalOcean. Here a user can upload a document but when he uploads an image, there is an error "[object Object]". Is this related to permissions.**

A command "ls -l" gives me this information on permissions:

```
itsme@MyWebsite:/var/www/html/public/contents/individual/project$ ls -l
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 31 04:29 cover
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 27 01:22 docs
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data 12288 Nov 27 01:23 images
```

**The directories "docs" and "images" have same permissions and located at same level. If "docs" is taking contents why "images" does not?**

Can someone help in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: `[object Object]` is not an error. Seems more like a JavaScript issue

Comment: Thanks Uby.
I am using same plugin to upload documents and image files. On Hostgator (shared Linux server), both are working. But on DigitalOcean, the plugin is having issues with images. Any clue, why it works fully on one server and partially on another.

Comment: whats the error exactly?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot every one for the input. Sorry my question was a bit unclear. But basically it was a problem with the ownership of the directories between /var and /images. www-data was supposed to be the owner of all the directories while in my case it was root as an owner. That is why the image plugin was showing [object Object] error/message. Though, I am still not sure, why "docs" folder was working and "images" not. But now I can upload contents in both folders.